# How to change class name when click?

Tags: jquery

I have icon lists, when I click icon, change class name to "icMark2" and when click again change "icMark3". 
Default class name is "icMark1" and there are total 4 classes.

So I tried, but i'm having trouble with handling the list of IDs.

Actually there are lot of icon items..
How do I have to fix the code ?

this is sample, when you see this, only first item works.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/bR2Y2/2/

please help me~~

```
    <span class="icMark">
     <a href="#" class="icMark1" id="list1"></a> <!-- icMark1 ~ icMark4 -->
     </span> 

    <span class="icMark">
     <a href="#" class="icMark1" id="list2"></a> <!-- icMark1 ~ icMark4 -->
     </span> 

    <span class="icMark">
     <a href="#" class="icMark1" id="list3"></a> <!-- icMark1 ~ icMark4 -->
     </span> 


<style>
    span {display:block; margin:0 0 20px 0; }
    span a { display:block; width:30px; height:30px; }

    .icMark1 {background:gray }
    .icMark2 {background:blue }
    .icMark3 {background:red }
    .icMark4 {background:green }

    </style>

<script>
    var classes = new Array("icMark1","icMark2","icMark3","icMark4");
                var idx = 0;

                $("#list1").on("click", changeClass);

                function changeClass() {
                    idx++;
                    var nextClass = classes[idx % classes.length];
                    $("#list1").attr("class",nextClass);
                }



</script>
```

Comment: Always put your code in the question.

Comment: Can you show what were you tried and what happened

Comment: I suppose each item should change its class independently of each other?

Comment: @jack / yeah it should change independently on each items

Comment: Don't forget to `preventDefault()` or return false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `.data()`,

```
var classes = new Array("icMark1", "icMark2", "icMark3", "icMark4");

$("#list1,#list2,#list3").on("click", changeClass);

function changeClass() {
    var no = $(this).data('no') || 1;
    var nextClass = classes[no % classes.length];
    $(this).attr("class", nextClass);
    no++;
    $(this).data('no', no);
}
```

### [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bR2Y2/5/)

Comment: What if he wanted to start one of the other anchors on 2, 3 or 4?

Comment: thankyou for your answer, but the list items can be hundreds. Is there any way to make ID name be dynamically ?

Comment: @user3758718 you can use attribute starts with selector or you can add a common class to all those hundred elements.. wait let me make a demo for that..

Comment: [Unexpected results when the class is something other than `icMark1` by default](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bR2Y2/15/)

Answer (score 1):

### [Working Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bR2Y2/16/)

- Use a generic selector - like a class selector. In this case bind click on `.icMark a` or `span a`
- And the `idx` won't affect the elements independently. Use
  `.indexOf()` to get the next class from the array.

---

```
$(".icMark a").on("click", changeClass);

function changeClass() {
    var cclass = $(this).attr("class");
    var nextClass = classes[(classes.indexOf(cclass)+1) % (classes.length)];
    $(this).attr("class", nextClass);
}
```

Comment: What happens when you get to icMark4? Does it look for icMark5?

Comment: @scrowler Ohh right, updated. Didn't think of that scenario. Good find!

Comment: Breaks if you introduce another class on the element, i.e. `class="foo icMark2"`

Comment: @Jack , scrowler Seems there can be many scenarios/cases to this when it fails. But OP needed an answer, he accepted one. Seems OP has to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class called `list` to all the elements

```
<a href="#" class="icMark1 list" id="list1"></a>
```

then

```
var classes = new Array("icMark1", "icMark2", "icMark3", "icMark4");
$(".list").on("click", changeClass);

function changeClass() {
    var $this = $(this),
        //get the current class index, 0 by default
        idx = $this.data('idx') || 0;
    //remove the previous class
    $this.removeClass(classes[idx]);
    //find the new index
    idx = (idx + 1) % classes.length;
    //add the new class
    $this.addClass(classes[idx])
    //save the state
    $this.data('idx', idx);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/arunpjohny/PY9S9/)

OR

```
var classes = new Array("icMark1", "icMark2", "icMark3", "icMark4");
$(".list").on("click", changeClass);

function changeClass() {
    var $this = $(this),
        idx = (($this.data('idx') || 0) + 1) % classes.length;
    $this.data('idx', idx);
    console.log(idx)
    $this.removeClass(classes.join(' ')).addClass(classes[idx])
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/arunpjohny/9HnFz/)

Comment: [Unexpected results when the class isn't defined as icMark1 by default](http://fiddle.jshell.net/9HnFz/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure what exactly you are looking for. If you want to change the class of all the icons when you click on the first one just add like this.

var classes = new Array("icMark1","icMark2","icMark3","icMark4");
            var idx = 0;

```
        $("#list1").on("click", changeClass);

        function changeClass() {
            idx++;
            var nextClass = classes[idx % classes.length];
            $("#list1").attr("class",nextClass);
            $("#list2").attr("class",nextClass);
            $("#list3").attr("class",nextClass);
        }
```

Or if you want to have the onclick action seperately for all the icons then do like 
Rajaprabhu have mentioned. I don't know what is the use of data().

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that observes the original class, in case you wanted one to be `icMark3` for example on page load:

```
function changeClass(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't forget this! doesn't matter in jsfiddle but...
    var idx = $(this).attr('class').replace('icMark', '');
    var nextClass = classes[idx % classes.length];
    $(this).attr("class", nextClass);
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/7WndG/1/)

Comment: Interesting; though, it will break when you add another class to an element, i.e. `class="something icMark1"`.

Answer (score -1):

I have modified your Fiddle please check here [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/madhust/bR2Y2/7/)

```
<span class="icMark">
 <a href="#" class="icMark1 list"></a> 
</span> 


 <span class="icMark">
 <a href="#" class="icMark1 list"></a> 
 </span> 

<script>
var classes = new Array("icMark1","icMark2","icMark3","icMark4");
        var idx = 0;

        $(".list").on("click", changeClass);

        function changeClass() {
            idx++;
            var nextClass = classes[idx % classes.length];
            $(this).attr("class",nextClass);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: @scrowler what do you mean elements dont change individually?

Comment: If you click one, then the other, the classes (colours) don't change individually, they affect each other.

Answer (score -1):

Made a small change with in your code

Try the below :

```
     var classes = new Array("icMark1","icMark2","icMark3","icMark4");
 var idx = 0;

 $("span.icMark a").on("click", changeClass);


 function changeClass() {
            if($(this).hasClass("icMark1")){alert("fd");
              $(this).switchClass("icMark1","icMark2");   
            }else if($(this).hasClass("icMark2")){
                 $(this).switchClass("icMark2","icMark3");   
            }else if($(this).hasClass("icMark3")){
                 $(this).switchClass("icMark3","icMark4");   
            }else {
                  $(this).switchClass("icMark4","icMark1"); 
            }

}
```

Nb: include jquery and jquery ui library

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6qcHB/2/)

Comment: -1 What if there were 100 classes? Are you going to make else ifs for each one?